# Encrypted disk in Windows 10, unreadable by macOS

Tags: macos, disk-utility, security, filesystem

I encrypted by external HDD with exFAT format using VeraCrypt on a windows machine. When I plug in the encrypted disk into MacBook (running macOS Mojave), I get the error "the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer". If I open VeraCrypt for mac and try to mount the disk, I get the error "hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems"

I have FUSE for macOS installed, before installed VeraCrypt.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you ask here:  https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/  Does it work when you attach the drive to another windows machine?  What options did you pick when you encrypted the drive?

Comment: @historystamp yes, it mounts perfectly fine on windows machine. I picked exFAT option for cross compatibility with windows, osx, and linux. AES 256, SHA 512. I did make a post there so let's see if I get any response.

Comment: What device did you use?  I'd assume you would give VeraCrypt a device name. If you encrypted the entire volume, you would use /dev/disk2.  If you encrypted the partition, you would use /dev/disk2s1.

Comment: @historystamp I tried mounting both the disk2 and the disk2s1. Both failed.

Comment: as a test  on your mac -- format a flash drive -- encrypt with VaraCrypt -- see if you can read it on your mac after you take the drive out then insert -- see if you can read it on Windows.